# Android Espresso - Single list with same items (AmbiguousViewMatcherException)

Tags: android-espresso

Trying to do learn Android Espresso test development.

I have a list which has two of the same items (same resource ID's, same text, only one list).

Currently I am doing this (probably very wrong):

```
DataInteraction dataInteraction = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withText("Test1"));

dataInteraction.atPosition(0).perform((click()));
```

This results is the exception:

```
I/TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
I/TestRunner: android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with text: is "Test1"' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
              Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
```

Layout is like this:

```
...

+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=128, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=65.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=xxxxxxxxx, res-name=image, visibility=VISIBLE, width=80, height=61, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=33.0}
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=xxxxxxx01, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=162, height=46, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=80.0, y=41.0, text=Test1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} ****MATCHES****
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=193.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=xxxxxxxxx, res-name=text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=All Tests, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---------->View{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=2, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=63.0}
|
+--------->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=128, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=258.0, child-count=2}
|
+---------->AppCompatImageView{id=xxxxxxxxx, res-name=image, visibility=VISIBLE, width=80, height=61, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=33.0}
|
+---------->AppCompatTextView{id=xxxxxxx01, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=162, height=46, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=80.0, y=40.0, text=Test1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} ****MATCHES****

...
```

The list is type:

```
ExpandableListView
```

It contains classes of type:

```
class TestType implements Serializable, Searchable
```

How do I click the items in the list by text or resource ID when I have multiple instances with the same information?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out I can click it like this:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(TestType.class)))).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

However a better way would be to include match for the text or resource ID contained in the TestType. instance.